# Create a Python dictionary with start and end values as the keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to translate this into a python dictionary or is there a better way to implement this.

I have a csv file with 3 columns. 1. Start 2. End 3. Value

eg Start, = 10, End = 90 Value = 30 ....Start=10000 End=30000 value =1

I thought I could do 10:30,11:30.....10000:1 for my dictionary, but how can I create this dictionary efficiently using the start and end as the keys.

Comment: dictionary[10,90] = 30

Comment: I need the dictionary to include all ranges between the start and end and it could go up to 80000 with different values.

Comment: No problem, pair will be your key

Comment: ok but how can I read 1000 rows of start and end in the csv and output it as pair(key)=value were pair =(start,end)?

Comment: Give a look to pandas.Interval, it could be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

csv:

```
Start,End,Value
10,20,30
100,334,534
122,3456,23
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
k = [*zip(df['Start'], df['End'])]
v = list(df['Value'])
d = dict(zip(k, v))
print(d)
```

Res:

```
{(10, 20): 30, (100, 334): 534, (122, 3456): 23}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the csv lib.

```
import csv

data = []

with open(filename) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if i == 0:  continue # skip header
        data.append({(int(row[0]), int(row[1])): int(row[2])}) # (note)
```

note: last `int` could be `float` depending of requested data type

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, this provides a lot of data processing primitives (brings code generation though).

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

converter = (
    c.iter({(c.item("Start"), c.item("End")): c.item("Value")})
    .as_type(list)
    .gen_converter()
)

rows = (
    Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=True)
    # cast all columns to int
    .update_all(int)
    # or .update(Start=c.col("Start").as_type(int)) to process one by one
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)

assert converter(rows) == [{(10, 20): 30}, {(100, 334): 534}, {(122, 3456): 23}]
```